# GATE Java error

Tags: java, gate

I know almost nothing about Java so please take it easy on me. I'm using this [plugin](https://github.com/antonydeepak/ResumeParser/tree/master/GATEFiles/bin), which I've had working nicely for a few days on my Mac (following the repo's very simple instructions below), but when I took it to an Ubuntu instance I got the following error:

```
ResumeParser/ResumeTransducer$ java -cp 'bin/*:../GATEFiles/lib/*:../GATEFILES/bin/gate.jar:lib/*' code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram somefile.pdf somefile.json
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gate/SimpleAnnotation
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gate.SimpleAnnotation
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Anyone have thoughts on what is going wrong?

Installation and usage instructions:

```
 1. git clone https://github.com/antonydeepak/ResumeParser.git
 2. cd ResumeParser/ResumeTransducer
 3. export GATE_HOME="..\GATEFiles"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths are case sensitive in Ubuntu, GATEFiles is different from GATEFILES. Since gate.SimpleAnnotation is in gate.jar, I bet that your classpath should be:

> -cp 'bin/*:../GATEFiles/lib/*:../GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:lib/*'

Disclaimer: I haven't used this plugin, I don't know if the other parts of the classpath are correct.

In general, you can "debug" by trying

> ls ../GATEFiles/bin/
>   to see if there is a gate.jar file.

Comment: Yes it was a case sensitivity issue. The 2nd `GATEFILES` should be `GATEFiles`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know, but most likely the class it cannot find is in the gate.jar file, and it is either not on the new machine, or is not in the correct place on the new machine.

To expand slightly: Classes are found in a couple of places, but you specify a gate.jar on the classpath of the command line (that's what the -cp designates), so I'm guessing it's there. Since java can't find it, I'm guessing further that the necessary jar file is not where it needs to be for the Java runtime to find it.

Comment: thanks any suggestions on how to change the `-cp` part?

Answer (score 1):

For Linux and OSX use '/' and ':' , try this call .. it worked for me

```
java -cp './bin/*:../GATEFiles/lib/*:../GATEFiles/bin/gate.jar:./lib/*' code4goal.antony.resumeparser.ResumeParserProgram cv.pdf cv.json
```